# return link click label xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using a renderer to list links to a text, when I click it it opens the browser. I want that when I click the link it indicates the clicked link and I return the value in a variable. What event in renderer do I check when it is triggered?

```
public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        SetHtmlText();
    }



    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        SetHtmlText();
    }

    private void SetHtmlText()
    {
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetText(GetSpannedHtml(), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
            Control.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance; // Makes links clickable
        }
    }

    private ISpanned GetSpannedHtml()
    {
        var source = Element?.Text ?? "";
        var html = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N
            ? Html.FromHtml(source, FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy)
            : Html.FromHtml(source);
        return html;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know of an event that is invoked when you click a label. But label is a view, so you can attach a Tapped GestureRecognizer and when its tapped, you can cast the sender to label and retrieve the text.

Comment: By `I return the value in a variable`, do you want to get a value when you click the label?

Comment: yes, when I click on the link I want to indicate in which link was clicked, because I have several links in the text, and show me in a DisplayAlert ("Alert", Link, "OK");